# Incorrect Number of binding supplied. the current statement uses 1, and there're 5 supplied

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a web application, I want to check if the username is existed or not in the database, also check password hash, as I'm hashing all passwords in the database , but I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. the current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied

Here's my code:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        with sqlite3.connect("finance.db") as con:
            username=request.form.get("username")
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username))
            con.commit()


        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        results = cur.fetchone()

        if results != 1 or not check_password_hash(results[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: Hmm... if you're getting a traceback, it should point you to a line. I'm guessing the error is coming from your sql query. What prints if you do `print(username)` before executing your `SELECT` query?

Comment: i'm getting the traceback on the line "cur.excute("SELECT *..."

Comment: it's like if i'm character in the row, and the row don't have a space, and the 5 supplied is the number of chars of the word that i put in the username, how could this may happen?, i'm really stuck,

Comment: Try changing `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username))` to `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", (username,))`. (Need the comma to create a tuple.)